# Why onLayout don't triggered in a SubText?

Tags: react-native

I'm with a issue about the onLayout event

A Code

```
<View>
  <Text>
    <Text onLayout={e => {console.log("this isn't triggered!")}}>{"foo"}</Text>
  </Text>
</View>
```

B Code

```
<View>
  <Text onLayout={e => {console.log("here the event it is called, but I need call in a SubText")}}>{"foo"}</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the inner Text in a View tag?

Comment: Somethink like

```<View>
  <Text>
    <View><Text onLayout={e => {console.log("this isn't triggered!")}}>{"foo"}</Text></View>[...]
  </Text>
</View>```

? Yep. :/

Comment: The Text component don't allow a View inside it.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot, but an alternative approach could be to use measure() instead of onLayout()

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer for posterity. I rolled through here before I finding my answer so maybe this will help someone else.

In my case, I needed to show attributed text in a scroll view and be able to scroll to different substrings within the text.

[Nesting texts within texts creates a single NSAttributedString behind the scenes on iOS and a SpannableString on Android](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text.html#nested-text), so trying to add an `onLayout` prop to a nested text element actually has no effect, since it's not actually represented as it's own text element in the resulting DOM.

In my case the solution was to [use the `onTextLayout` prop of the Text component](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text.html#ontextlayout):

```js
import React from "react"
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, Text, View } from "react-native"

const App = () => {
  const scrollViewRef = React.useRef<ScrollView>(null)

  const onTextLayout = React.useCallback(event => {
    const scrollLocation = event.nativeEvent.lines.find(
      line => line.text === "6. Hello\n",
    ).y
    if (scrollViewRef.current) {
      scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
        x: 0,
        y: scrollLocation,
        animated: true,
      })
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ height: 100 }}>
        <ScrollView
          ref={scrollViewRef}
          style={{
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            borderColor: "#000",
            borderWidth: 1,
          }}
        >
          <Text onTextLayout={onTextLayout}>
            <Text>1. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
            <Text>2. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
            <Text>3. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
            <Text>4. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
            <Text>5. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
            <Text>6. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
            <Text>7. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
            <Text>8. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
            <Text>9. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
            <Text>10. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
            <Text>10. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
            <Text>10. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
            <Text>10. Hello{"\n"}</Text>
          </Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
})

export default App
```

As a side note, I am getting Typescript errors on the line which uses the `onTextLayout=` prop. Googling for solutions doesn't turn anything up, but the prop function is called!

Answer (score 1):

I found this related bug on RN repo : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11650. Still looking for a way to measure nested texts